# Laravel Eloquent: how to list posts from different authors on a page?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to list posts from different authors on every page.

Ex: you chose to list 10 posts per page, and these 10 posts should be from different authors.

The Laravel Elequent should be used. What is the best way?

Comment: I'd normally select the first 10 authors with their posts and pick one per author.

Comment: You can select posts group by author_id and take first 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to define a `hasOne` relationship on the Author model ordering by the posts `created_at` column.

```
public function lastPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Post')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Then your query would be:

```
$authors = Author::with('lastPost')->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

> List 10 posts per page, and these 10 posts should be from different authors

```
Post::inRandomOrder()->groupBy('user_id')->take(10)->get();
```

I've tested it and it will give you what you want. However, it will always give you the same post for each author. So, authors will always be random, but each author's post will always be the same.

Another solution is to use `hasOne` relationship:

```
public function singlePost() {
    return $this->hasOne(Post::class);
}
```

And then:

```
Author::inRandomOrder()->with('singlePost')->take(10)->get();
```

If you want to get a random post for 10 random authors, create another relationship:

```
public function randomPost() {
    return $this->hasOne(Post::class)->inRandomOrder();
}
```

And then:

```
Author::inRandomOrder()->with('randomPost')->take(10)->get();
```

Be careful here, because `inRandomOrder()` is pretty slow and when you nest it, it can take too much time to get the data if tables are big.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$posts = Post::with('author')->take(10)->get();
```

When looping in view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->name }}
    {{ $post->author->name }}
@endforeach
```